# How to install a package from github into plain PHP in Xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I am a beginner in PHP and my confusion might sound weird. I want to use this package https://github.com/mtibben/html2text into a php code that I have written. Now I am unable to understand how to install this package on localhost. I am using XAMPP on windows 10 laptop.

Comment: Did you install Composer? If not intall that first and then use the instructions there on github

Comment: Or click on the Green CODE button and then click "Download Zip" on the dropdown you will be presented with. Then unzip the zip

Comment: Yes, I installed composer. 
"Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires docxpresso/html2text ^1.2 -> satisfiable by docxpresso/html2text[v1.2].
    - docxpresso/html2text v1.2 requires ext-tidy * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's tidy extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json."

Comment: Yes I downloaded the zip file but where in the XAMPP folder that file needs to be placed

Comment: In your documentRoot or a subfolder of that

Comment: documentRoot means "htdocs" folder? and how will that be inserted into my php code? Sorry for asking silly questions.

Comment: You `include` or `require` it in your PHP code

Comment: Ohk. Let me try this. Thank you for help